# Mamey seedling showing deficiencies that I couldn't fix

Tags: diagnosis, nutrients, tropical, soil-test, deficiency

I already lost one seedling in the same manner, leaves get yellow spots then the edges shrivel and the whole leaf dies and falls.

My soil test shows issues with micros obviously, I get very bright sun every day and the temps are hovering around 98 in Sunny Tunisia.

I do spray micros every now and then, but unhealthy leaves seem unlikely to take up nutrients, I'm about to drench with 1/2oz Sequestrene + 1/2oz Magnesium Sulfate, otherwise I usually fertilize with super light npk, I'm also thinking of adding 10gr of high Potassium NPK. Any other leads please.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Has it had any calcium? Magnesium and calcium need to  be in proper balance, I believe.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx I haven't given any Ca as the soil test shows plenty of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that kind of plant, but it looks and sounds like iron-deficiency, which causes chlorosis (yellowing) of new growth. Sulfur does, too, but you're giving it that.